# getting list of directories and files from ftp and putting them into wx.genericDirCtrl

Tags: wxpython

I want to connect to FTP server:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp.debian.org')
ftp.login()
```

and them put directories and files into wx.genericDirCtrl, so FTP could be browsed just like "normal" directories and files on hd...

I tried different ways, none of them work :(

Answer (score 0):

I had to connect() to the server before I could do login().
So, you should do sth like this:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('your_ftp_server')
ftp.connect()
ftp.login('your_ftp_login','your_ftp_password')
```

If everything went OK, after `ftp.connect()` you should see banner similar to:

`"220-Idea FTP Server v0.80 (your_ftp_server) [ip_address]\n220 Ready"`

then if username and password are valid:

`"230 'your_username' login ok."`

after login() is executed.